# Accessing all the attributes written

Tags: python

I hope you're doing well. I am writing this message, because I would like to have access to all the attributes written of an object. So in this case, below I would like to access the value of self.name, the value of self.age and the value of self.sex .
I tried with dir(self) but it doesn't give me just these 3 above

```
class test(object):
    def __init__(self,uut):     

        self.name="name"
        self.age= "age"
        self.sex="male"

        self.cross_count = ccc.cross((att, getattr(self,att)) for att in dir(self))
```

Comment: Maybe you want `self.__dict__`.

Comment: I recommend you take a look at data classes https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of them are under [`__dict__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#object.__dict__)

```
class test(object):
    def __init__(self):

        self.name = "name"
        self.age = "age"
        self.sex = "male"

        att = [(k, v) for k, v in (self.__dict__.items())] # or just att = list(self.__dict__.items())
        # __dict__ is just a simple python dictionary. You can use .values() if you want only values
        values = [v for v in (self.__dict__.values())]

        print(att)

test()
```

Comment: Alright that's perfect ! What if I just want the value ?

Comment: Edited an answer